# Setting the order of attribute when writing XML Element

Tags: java, xml

When writing in java the following:

```
Element fieldEl = targetDocument.createElement("field");
fieldEl.setAttribute("Wine","Marlo");
fieldEl.setAttribute("Beer","Corona");
```

The order of adding the attributes are not kept in the result XML file. 
How can I control the order of the attribute inside XML Element (so it will be easy for human being to read...) ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no defined order for attribute nodes according to the [DOM standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-DOM-Level-1-19981001/level-one-core.html#ID-1780488922):

> Objects implementing the NamedNodeMap interface are used to represent collections of nodes that can be accessed by name. Note that NamedNodeMap does not inherit from NodeList; NamedNodeMaps are not maintained in any particular order. **Objects contained in an object implementing NamedNodeMap may also be accessed by an ordinal index, but this is simply to allow convenient enumeration of the contents of a NamedNodeMap, and does not imply that the DOM specifies an order to these Nodes.**

(emphasis added) and neither in the [XML standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-starttags):

> Note that the order of attribute specifications in a start-tag or empty-element tag is not significant.

I don't think, that many DOM implementations support ordering of attributes at all. You'd have to write your own serialization mechanism in order to achieve ordering (no pun intended).

Comment: no, that's xml standard. If you want ordered values, put your information in elements.